# JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet window appears blank

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

After update of **`Chrome 54.0.2840.16 beta-m (64-bit)`**, JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet window appears blank, all the sections(HTML, JavaScript, CSS and Result) are invisible.

After inspecting the `Snippet-window`, All the four elements, `column html`, `column css`, `column js` and `column result` are having height **`0`**.

Editing the height of those elements using *`Developers-tools`* make them appear!

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Chrome 53.0.2785.113 on Linux Mint.

Comment: @Gothdo – I have updated the version. I am been facing this issue since a week or so ad I was using `53.*` version earlier.. I could reproduce the same on `53.*` version on `BrowserStack`

Comment: @Gothdo – That is exact dupe.. How do I find the answer/solution ?

Comment: @Rayon there is no answer or solution yet.

Comment: Is there any way I can rollback `chrome` on stable release ?

Comment: @All – Installing stable release `53.0.2785.113 m (64-bit)` solved my problem!

Thanks a lot :)